# How do I fix this google app engine error python?

Tags: google-app-engine

```
(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Flex operation projects/foodsaver-389619/regions/us-east1/operations/59970397-c141-4602-be7d-fd9232196f00 error [DEADLINE_EXCEEDED]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2023-06-13T02:00:02.058Z15870.ue.0: Gave up polling Deployment Manager operation foodsaver-389619/operation-1686621602419-5fdf9317b94dd-dc7af4d8-ad713c10.
```

i ran /Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud app deploy

Comment: you should run the command with verbose flag to reveal more details.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, i had to change my app.yaml entrypoint to gunicorn --timeout 1000 app:app